Looking for the wave? function's formula
Sorry if this is a very primitive question. But can someone please help me find the formula for the following function?

I believe it's called a wave function but I'm not sure since when I search online for wave functions, quantum physics web pages dominate the results which makes it hard to find the formula for this function.

There is an infinite set of functions that look similar to this e.g. the derivative of functions of the form $f(x) =\frac{-1}{a^2+x^2}$. You are going to have to narrow it down with some context.

Tukey’s biweight and Andrew’s sine may help

This looks like $y = xe^{-x^2}$ (related to the derivative of the normal distribution) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fn8nnnqilj

You're correct. It's called a wave function, but it doesn't always look like that. Here is an image of an animated version. You can't find an exact equation but you can find ones similar to it. There's not enough context to get the equation as Paul commented.
If you want to use TomKen's answer to make the function bigger, just put give the $x$ value a co-efficient.
$y=4xe^{-x^2}$ seems perfect.
